# INSERT INTO Statement not working PHP/MySQLI

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I've combed through this site non-stop looking for the solution to my problems but have come up empty handed still.
Here's the problem, whenever I use the following `INSERT INTO` statement nothing is inserted into my database, the code runs without a hitch but at the end of the day my database is still empty(excluding values I manually inserted myself). 
I would also like to point out that I ran a `SELECT FROM` statement that returned manually inserted values from the database nicely. 
Anyway here's the code:

Connecting to database

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prototype");
```

Insert code

```
  if ($error) echo "There were error(s) in your signup details:".$error;
else
{

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  echo $results;

  if ($results) echo " This email address is already taken. Would you like to log in?";
  else
  {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']).', '.md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);

    echo "You've been registered!";

    $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($link);

    print_r($_SESSION);

    // Redirect to logged in page

  }
```

Comment: What happens if you use `mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($link));` instead? Does it give you a meaningful error?

Comment: Here's an idea about how to debug this:  echo the contents of the string containing the SQL statement. Then take a careful look at the SQL statement. I think you are going to discover that VALUES () contains a single string literal, and not two string literals. Here's another idea:  check the return from mysqli_query to verify the statement execution is successful. And if not, use `mysqli_error` to return the MySQL error message. And here's another idea: the MD5 algorithm is suitable for verifying *integrity* of a message, but it's *not* a good choice for password hashing.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/   Was there a *question* you intended to ask?  Or were just providing a status report?

Comment: Hey Spencer I appreciate your help, sorry about the post though. I've been using stack overflow for a long time now but this is my first time actually asking a question. I'll take your tips and try to ask a better one next time.

Comment: When i echo $query I get the following: INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('navid@navid.com', '3a3da8786305e14b86e094b653b0b5d2')You've been signed up!

Comment: Spencer can you explain to me how to check the the return of the mysqli_query?

Comment: @spencer7593 can you explain how I can check the return of the mysqli_query?

Comment: @NavwhalGuy: `mysqli_query` will evaluate to FALSE if the execution is unsuccessful. I've seen examples of PHP code doing something like this:  **`if(!mysqli_query(...) { /* MySQL error available from mysqli_error() */ `**.

Comment: @spencer7593 okay thank you very much, I'll try it out

Comment: Hi @spencer7593, I set up the following statement and it returned TRUE what should I do to find exactly where the error lies? 
        if(!mysqli_query($link, $query))
        {
          echo "TRUE";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "FALSE";
        }

Comment: **`{ echo mysqli_error($link); }`**   see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  (In my first comment on this question, I recommended you use this function to return the MySQL error. I also indicated that the code in the question  makes it look like the VALUES has only a *single* string literal. (The single quote characters around the comma delimit a PHP string, those will  *not* be included as part of the SQL text.

Comment: @spencer7593 I cannot believe this man i found the problem, it said 'name' didnt have a default value and then I set a value for it. Thank you so much man

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your insert query as below

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
```